# please explain this function used to find index of highest number in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays

We have not defined greatest. So how can we check against it in the if statement.

```
function findIndexOfGreatest(array) {
  var greatest;
  var indexOfGreatest;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!greatest || array[i] > greatest) {
      greatest = array[i];
      indexOfGreatest = i;
    }
  }
  return indexOfGreatest;
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @Fei javascript

Comment: You should add the JavaScript tag to the question to people can more easily find it.

Comment: Just did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With `!greatest` you check if `greatest` has a not falsy value. It´s not the best way to check for `undefined` nor `null`, because `0` will give you also a `true` (`!(0 == true)`) - and some other values too.

A cleaner way would be to set `greatest` initial to the `smallest number - 1` you expect, or check against `undefined`:

```
 if (typeof greatest === 'undefined' || array[i] > greatest)
```

It also would be better to set `indexOfGreatest` to `-1` for `no index found`, like other 
`indexOf` functions does.

As reference see [String.indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp):

> This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findIndexOfGreatest(array) {

  //storage for the current highest value in the array
  var greatest;
  //storage for the index of the highest value in the array
  var indexOfGreatest;

  //iterate over the array
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //if no greates value yet, or current element is greater then current greatest
    if (!greatest || array[i] > greatest) {
      //store index and value of current element
      greatest = array[i];
      indexOfGreatest = i;
    }
  }
  return indexOfGreatest;
}
```

Like also @take noted: `!greatest` will screw up this algorithm if the array contains values like `[-1, 0, -3, -5, -7]` because in the second iteration `greatest` will be set to `0` and `!0` will evaluate to `true` in the third iteration, thus setting the `greatest = -3` and `indexOfGreatest = 2` which is obviously wrong.

Shorter and safer version:

```
function findIndexOfGreatest(array) {
   //if array is empty return -1 as indicating invalid index
   if (!array.length) return -1;

   //index of the greates element is assumed to be first element
   let index = 0;
   //iterate from the second element in the array to the end
   for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
       //check if the current element is greater then the element at the stored index. If yes, update index to point to the current element
       if (array[i] > array[index]) index = i;
   return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Hamid**, first have a look at the following JS statements executed on **Node REPL**.

```
> var greatest;
undefined
>
> !greatest
true
>
> // Let's assign some value to greatest
undefined
>
> greatest = 4
4
> !greatest
false
>
> // Understanding the work of || operator
undefined
>
> 1 || 2
1
>
> 11 || 2
11
>
> 0 || 2
2
>
> true || 88
true
>
> false || 88
88
>
> var a
undefined
>
> a || 10
10
>
> !a || 10
true
>
```

> You can check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators to know more about the working of `||` operator.

So in the statement `!greatest || array[i] > greatest`, `!greatest` will be evaluated as `!undefined` which is `true` and its only for first iteration.

For latter iterations, `!greatest` will be evaluated as `false` and the code inside if block only gets evaluated if `array[i] > greatest` is `true`.

> **expr1 || expr2**, returns **expr1** if it can be converted to `true`; otherwise, returns **expr2**. Thus, when used with Boolean values, `||` returns `true` if either operand is `true`.

You can also try the below code.

> I have used **reduce()** method defined on array to get the maximum element.
>
> After this it is very easy to find the index of item using **indexOf()** method defined on array.

```js
function findIndexOfGreatest(array) {
   var greatest;
   var indexOfGreatest

   greatest = array.reduce((num1, num2) => {
  if(num1 > num2) {
   return num1
  } else {
   return num2
  }
   })

   indexOfGreatest = array.indexOf(greatest);
   return indexOfGreatest
}

// TEST
var array = [0, -1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 8, 22, 11, -4, 7, 5, 3, 9]
var indexOfGreatest = findIndexOfGreatest(array)  

console.log(indexOfGreatest) // 8 (index of 22 in array)
```

Comment: One remark regarding your alternative: This will iterate the array on average 1.5 times. Once for performing the `reduce`. And a second time searching the `indexOf`. 1.5 because the greatest element may be the first in best case, but also last in worst case. So on average indexOf will search half the array.